# confused about ubuntu / xubuntu releases

Tags: updates, xubuntu, xfce

Initially I had Ubuntu installed, but later I switched to xubuntu by installing the xfce desktop, and removed the ubuntu-desktop, but now I`m confused about the release update because the updater says that there a new update: Ubuntu 13.10 'Saucy Salamander' and if I look in the sysinfo app it says that I have Ubuntu 13.04 (raring), Gnome 3.6.3, but I have Xubuntu.

if I do the update, then it will switch back to the ubuntu-desktop, or how can I make the Xubuntu release update without installing the ubuntu-desktop?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu and Xubuntu both share the same repositories, so no matter what desktop environment you have installed, it will upgrade to the next release.

If the upgrade goes well after doing:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

You will still have your Xubuntu, or what is the same, your Ubuntu with the xfce desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the desktop doesn't change the version of Ubuntu or any of it's "flavors" (Xubuntu, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, etc), but the different desktop environments have their own numbers.

I use Xubuntu 12.04, for example, but my *desktop* is Xfce4.8. In Xubuntu 13.10 the desktop is Xfce4.10!  The desktop versions don't always keep pace with the 'buntu versions.

When you update your computer, everything (including all installed desktops) is updated according to the *Ubuntu* version (Precise 12.04, Raring 3.10, etc) you have installed.

I hope that is helpful.